# Why is it אלו הן הלוקין rather than אלו הן הנלקין?

Tags: grammar-dikduk, maseches-makos

Looking for an explanation as to why the פעל form is used rather than נפעל. Instead of “These are the ones who hit” I would’ve expected it to be “these are the ones who are hit.” One thought would be that it’s shortened from something like “these are the ones that we hit” but I don’t find that to be a satisfactory answer.

Comment: לקה always means to be punished, to suffer etc. (See https://www.sefaria.org.il/Jastrow%2C_לקי.1?lang=bi). Even though it’s pa’al, the sense is passive. The active ‘to hit’ is conveyed by the hif’il.

Comment: In other words, לקה means to take a hit, not to hit. The word for hitting is מלקה

Comment: https://www.academia.edu/42970112/The_Shift_of_Intransitive_Verbs_into_Passive_Conjugations_in_Mishnaic_Hebrew_%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%91%D7%A8_%D7%A9%D7%9C_%D7%A4%D7%A2%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%9C%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%94%D7%A1%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%91%D7%9C%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9F_%D7%97%D7%96_%D7%9C

Answer (score 1):

Good point, first, I want to strengthen your question by providing a Talmudic example:

> "שמעתי שכל הזורע ברביעה ראשונה **ברד מלקה אותו**.
> הלך הוא וזרע ברביעה שניה. של כל העולם כולו **לקה, שלו לא לקה**." [Berakhot.18b](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.18b.7?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

As we can see here, לקה is used in direct connection with הלקה (הפעיל) suggesting a passive form. *(Maybe you should copy it to your question.)*

I would offer two propositions (there are no true explanations, of course):

1. If you look at other usages of the word it is closer to signifying a state, such as Hebrew גדל, or חסר, or כואב, or חולה. For example: "כהן שלקה באצבעו כורך עליו גמי" ([JT Eruvin 64a](https://www.sefaria.org/Jerusalem_Talmud_Eruvin.64a.2?vhe=Mechon_Mamre_Talmud_Yerushalmi&lang=bi)), "החושד בכשרים לוקה בגופו" ([Shabbat.97a](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.97a.4?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)). So like saying "אני מכאיב לו והוא כואב", we can say "אני מלקה אותו והוא לוקה".
2. The word ללקות is originally Mishnaic (Aramaic), not Biblical, so Rabbis were free to put it in any form they like. In my observation (as a native Hebrew speaker) they weren't particularly grammar-savvy, as Hebrew wasn't spoken language at their times. To wit, they frequently use weird grammatical forms (like הן לוקין instead of הם לוקים, confusing לקרות and לקרוא), disagreement in gender, and more.

Comment: The Malbim and others have shown that Chazal knew grammar perfectly well, they just didn't stress about it too much if it didn't affect the meaning. You don't have to be an expert to know gender should agree; everyone knows that; they just didn't care.

Comment: They speculated a-priori, they didn't show. It's "because they were wise" it's reasonable to assume they knew Hebrew grammar.

Comment: How does the first point strengthen the question? It shows that the הפעיל is the active form, and the kal is the passive form. This answers the question, doesn't strengthen it

Comment: @wfb Because when shown in contrast to הפעיל it becomes obvious that this form is passive. Otherwise, you can't infer something from the translation alone.

Answer (score 1):

The Rashba (IIRC, siman 694 in teshuvos) deals with a similar question: Why does the Mishna always refer to the man doing chalitza, when in reality it is the woman who performs chalitza? He answers that the Mishna doesn't usually care about these issues when it is just a matter of grammar and there is no room for error in understanding.

Comment: How a smart person can say, that the wisest of men "didn't care" and wrote it intentionally wrong?

Comment: @AlBerko It isn't intentionally wrong, more like not getting caught up in small details. (Like I made my last sentence a comma splice but didn't bother to fix it because you get the point.) My answer fits better with them being the wisest of men than yours does.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand how smart people can write wrong sentences. Many leading contemporary rabbis speak (and write) bad Hebrew because they don't speak it. How are they different from the sages?

Comment: Smart people can choose to ignore details that are unimportant.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer that this is just a theory, but here goes:

The Tiferes Yisrael to Arachin Ch. 4 theorizes that many of the oddities of Mishna could be explained as means to help memorization. (See [Tosafos](https://www.sefaria.org/Megillah.32a.12?lang=he&p2=Tosafot_on_Megillah.32a.12.1&lang2=he&w2=all&lang3=he) to Megillah) He uses this to explain extraneous halachos (such as *Lo zu af zu* and *Zu v'ein tzarich lomar zu*) and also cases of the Gemara saying the Mishnah is missing words (חסורי מחסרא והכי קתני).

Perhaps this could also explain Mishnayos switching terms from passive to active voice. This would be a technique to make the Mishnah more memorable, without sacrificing clarity.